# Mercurial Configuration

Tags: mercurial

I've read the quick guides and tutorial for installing Mercurial on my local server to share with my teammates but i can figure out how to set it up correctly.

I have a windows environment but i work from the command line, i create a repo:

```
hg init myproject
```

this creates the project that i can clone from but i cant push to it, i get the following message

```
"abort: destination does not support push"
```

but how do i create a "master" repo that i can push and pull from on my local server?

any idea? thank you.

Comment: Just install it https://rhodecode.com/ PS: oh, windows o_O

Answer (score 0):

You need to show the command you're trying to use to push to it.  How are you giving the name of where to push to?  Is it a http: URL (if so you need to run a server)?  Is it a file path?  Is it a windows share?

Any of those 3 will work, but you'll probably find things easier to use a windows share.  Just have people clone from and push to your crazy windows UNC path and you should be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Mercurial is distributed source control, so there's no real concept of a 'master' repo besides what you and your team enforce. Right now the repo you init-ed can be pulled from and pushed to by anyone ( if you 'hg serve' it ), and the same applies to every clone of that repo.

I'm not sure if you mean the box you init-ed on is the one you want to be the 'master', but I will assume you want it on a server somewhere else. To have a master repo, you would have to either init one on the server box, or clone the one on your local box on the server box. And then you will have to 'hg serve' that server's clone.

One caveat is that while every repo is its own master, each repo does remember where it was cloned from, and uses that as the default push/pull repo. So if you have anyone clone a repo from the server, any pushes or pulls on that clone will by default target the server box. You can still push/pull to other clones of the same repo by specifying their urls' or directories when you push/pull. You can change the default repo at anytime by editing the .hg\hgrc file in your repo.